# How to get rid of Unary Operator expected in shell script

Tags: shell

Why do I keep getting "Unary Operator expected", even though my code runs and outputs correctly? It's just a simple array bubble sort.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a array
hold=0

echo "Input length of array: "
read length

for((i = 0; i < length; i++))
do
        echo "Enter number: "
        read input
        array+=($input)
done

echo " "
echo "Elements in array: "
echo "${array[*]}"

echo " "
echo "Sorted Array"

for((i = 0; i < $length; i++))
do
        for((j = 0; j < $length; j++))
        do
                if [ ${array[j]} -gt ${array[$((j+1))]} ]
                then
                        hold=${array[j]}
                        array[$j]=${array[$((j+1))]}
                        array[$((j+1))]=$hold
                fi
        done
done

echo "Sorted Elements in array: "
echo "${array[*]}"
```

Comment: Please format your code in the question, read minimal requirements how to ask questions, as before helping you i have to fix your code example

Comment: Implementing bubble sort is kind of a waste of time. You don't write programs like this in shell script: you write code that runs other programs.

Answer (score 0):

Use (( )) for math operations code will be more readable as you don't need special symbols
https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2219

your problem place is :
`if [ ${array[j]} -gt ${array[$((j+1))]} ]`
replace on
`if (( array[j] > array[j+1] ))`

Improved version of your code :

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a array 
declare hold=0

# echo "Input length of array: " 
#read length

#for (( i = 0; i < length; i++ )); do 
#   echo "Enter array number: $i" ;
#   read input 
#   array+=($input) 
# done

array=(6 7 2 3 8 9)
length=${#array[@]}

echo "************************"
echo "Elements in array: " 
echo "${array[*]}"
echo "************************"

for (( i = 0; i < length; i++ )); do    
    
    for (( j = 0; j < length -1 ; j++ )); do         
        #echo "iteration i/j - $i/$j ${array[*]} "                      
        if (( array[j] > array[j+1] )); then            
            hold=array[j]
            array[j]=array[j+1]
            array[j+1]=hold
            echo "change ${array[*]} " 
        fi 

    done 
done

echo "************************"
echo "Sorted Elements in array: " 
echo "${array[*]}"
echo "************************"
```

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) warns [Instead of `let expr`, prefer `(( expr ))`](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2219).

Comment: You don't need `let` or `((...))` for the assignments. Array indices are evaluated in an arithmetic context. `array[j]=array[j+1]` works fine.

Comment: The _unquoted_ argument to `let` is subject to word splitting and glob expansion, like any other ordinary command. A contrived, but valid, example: `array=(5 7 9); j=0; array1=42; touch "arrayj=array1"; set -x; let array[j]=array[j+1]; set +x; declare -p array arrayj; ((array[j] = array[j+1])); declare -p array arrayj`

Comment: tested here : https://replit.com/languages/bash 
this what i got : 
main.sh: line 27: j+1: expression recursion level exceeded (error token is "j+1")

Comment: You glossed over the important fix: ending the inner loop before `j` gets too big.

Comment: @chepner it is there :  length -1

Comment: @Arkon88, `let expr` (legacy ksh extension) vs `(( expr ))` (modern bash extension) can be argued to be a matter of taste, but `$(( expr ))` -- as part of the POSIX.2 specification -- is unambiguously more widely compatible than either. Personally, I _do_ use the bash extension, and I don't mean to be arguing against it, but I'd argue that `let` is never the best choice.

Comment: @Arkon88 Yes, but you don't even mention that you made that fix. The stuff about `let` and `((...))` isn't what solved the problem.

Comment: In `declare hold=0`, `declare` isn't doing anything.